# CSS grid with fixed widths for some columns

Tags: html, css, grid, css-grid

I am trying to achieve this layout by using CSS grid.

Picture:

[image]

This is what I have so far:

```css
#wrapper {
    display: grid;
    gap: 20px;
    grid-template-columns: auto 300px 1fr 1fr 180px auto;
    grid-template-rows: auto;
    grid-template-areas: 
    "logo nav-primary nav-primary nav-primary nav-primary search"
    "nav-secondary nav-secondary nav-secondary nav-secondary nav-secondary nav-secondary"
    "aside-1 aside-1 article article aside-2 aside-2"
    "footer footer footer footer footer footer";
}

/* Article: use up remaining width */
#article{
    grid-area: article;
}

/* Logo: use up a little width as possible */
#logo{
    grid-area: logo;
}

/* Nav Primary: use up remaining width */
#nav-primary{
    grid-area: nav-primary;
}

/* Nav Secondary: use full width */
#nav-secondary{
    grid-area: nav-secondary;
}

/* Search: use up a little width as possible */
#search{
    grid-area: search;
}

/* Aside 1: fixed with of 300px */
#aside-1{
    grid-area: aside-1;
}

/* Aside 2: fixed with of 180px */
#aside-2{
    grid-area: aside-2;
}

/* Footer: use full width */
#footer{
    grid-area: footer;
}

/* Demo style */
#wrapper > * {
    background: #C4C4C4;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
    <article id="article">Article (use up remaining space)</article>
    <header id="logo">Logo</header>
    <nav id="nav-primary">Nav Primary</nav>
    <nav id="nav-secondary">Nav Secondary</nav>
    <form id="search">Search Form</form>
    <aside id="aside-1">Aside 1 (fixed width: 300px)</aside>
    <aside id="aside-2">Aside 2 (fixed width: 180px)</aside>
    <footer id="footer">Footer</footer>
</div>
```

Codepen: https://codepen.io/aobrien/pen/YzwNZpy

The issue is that Aside1 is not 300px, but instead 300px + the width of the logo column. Same for Aside2, its 180px + the width of the search column.
I can’t seem to set a fixed width for Aside1 and Aside2, while at the same time having the logo and the search be dynamic in width to fit their content and be as small as possible.

The logo box must always be as small as possible so it only fits the content. Same for the search, as small as possible.

Aside1 needs to have a fixed width of `300px` and Aside2 needs to have a fixed width of `180px`.

My only rule is, I cannot make any changes to the HTML structure as seen, so no nesting of these items. However I can add new HTML elements inside of the current elements, which could contain a fixed width (if that helps?).

I don’t have to rely on `grid-template-areas`, it can be an explicit or implicit grid. It can also contain more columns if it somehow helps. Any changes to the CSS are welcome.

The only solution I seem to have had so far (which is not a solution I want to settle for) is to assign a fixed width to the logo and the search and then calculate the remaining width to achieve the width of Aside1 and Aside2. However this is really not what I was looking for as I would like to keep it as dynamic as possible without the need to manually set multiple fixed widths across the layout.

Another solution I tried was instead of defining a fixed width of Aside1 via `grid-template-columns`, I could create a new div inside of Aside1 and give that a `width: 300px` and set `grid-template-columns` to `auto` for that column. This does work except if the logo gets wider than 300px then Aside1 becomes wider than 300px as well.

Does anyone have any solutions or pointers that could help me out?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all you have 6 columns, but we can keep only 5 for this task. Second - we don't need to set fixed width in `grid-template-columns` if we are going to use t cells collapsing. Match easier to set fixed width for specific columns. Here you go

```css
#wrapper {
  display: grid;
  gap: 15px;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto 1fr auto auto;
  grid-template-rows: auto;
 grid-template-areas: 
    "logo nav-primary nav-primary nav-primary search"
    "nav-secondary nav-secondary nav-secondary nav-secondary nav-secondary"
    "aside-1 aside-1 article aside-2 aside-2"
    "footer footer footer footer footer";
}


/* Article: use up remaining width */

#article {
  grid-area: article;
}


/* Logo: use up a little width as possible */

#logo {
  grid-area: logo;
  max-width: 300px;
}


/* Nav Primary: use up remaining width */

#nav-primary {
  grid-area: nav-primary;
}


/* Nav Secondary: use full width */

#nav-secondary {
  grid-area: nav-secondary;
}


/* Search: use up a little width as possible */

#search {
  grid-area: search;
  max-width: 180px;
}


/* Aside 1: fixed with of 300px */

#aside-1 {
  grid-area: aside-1;
  width: 300px;
}


/* Aside 2: fixed with of 180px */

#aside-2 {
  grid-area: aside-2;
  width: 180px;
}


/* Footer: use full width */

#footer {
  grid-area: footer;
}


/* Demo style */

#wrapper>* {
  background: #C4C4C4;
  padding: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <article id="article">Article (use up remaining space)</article>
  <header id="logo">Logo</header>
  <nav id="nav-primary">Nav Primary</nav>
  <nav id="nav-secondary">Nav Secondary</nav>
  <form id="search">Search Form</form>
  <aside id="aside-1">Aside 1 (fixed width: 300px)</aside>
  <aside id="aside-2">Aside 2 (fixed width: 180px)</aside>
  <footer id="footer">Footer</footer>
</div>
```

Note that in this case your Logo should be less than 300px width. And Search should be less than 180px width. If you want Search to be wider than 180px - we should edit the code a bit.

```css
#wrapper {
  display: grid;
  gap: 15px;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto 1fr auto auto auto;
  grid-template-rows: auto;
 grid-template-areas: 
    "logo nav-primary nav-primary search search search"
    "nav-secondary nav-secondary nav-secondary nav-secondary nav-secondary nav-secondary"
    "aside-1 aside-1 article article aside-2 aside-2"
    "footer footer footer footer footer footer";
}


/* Article: use up remaining width */

#article {
  grid-area: article;
}


/* Logo: use up a little width as possible */

#logo {
  grid-area: logo;
  max-width: 300px;
}


/* Nav Primary: use up remaining width */

#nav-primary {
  grid-area: nav-primary;
}


/* Nav Secondary: use full width */

#nav-secondary {
  grid-area: nav-secondary;
}


/* Search: use up a little width as possible */

#search {
  grid-area: search;
}


/* Aside 1: fixed with of 300px */

#aside-1 {
  grid-area: aside-1;
  width: 300px;
}


/* Aside 2: fixed with of 180px */

#aside-2 {
  grid-area: aside-2;
  width: 180px;
}


/* Footer: use full width */

#footer {
  grid-area: footer;
}


/* Demo style */

#wrapper>* {
  background: #C4C4C4;
  padding: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <article id="article">Article (use up remaining space)</article>
  <header id="logo">Logo</header>
  <nav id="nav-primary">Nav Primary</nav>
  <nav id="nav-secondary">Nav Secondary</nav>
  <form id="search">Search Form</form>
  <aside id="aside-1">Aside 1 (fixed width: 300px)</aside>
  <aside id="aside-2">Aside 2 (fixed width: 180px)</aside>
  <footer id="footer">Footer</footer>
</div>
```

Comment: Good answer. Note that you can set max-width 300px to logo

Comment: Yeah, thanks a lot! Added it to the answer. The same thing with Search.

Comment: Amazing, thank you. However, what if the logo is wider than 300px? Is there a simple solution for that? The only solution that comes to mind is for the logo to span across 2 columns and aside1 to span across 1 column (basically reversing them). I can't think of a more simple (dynamic) solution that wouldn't require changing the amount of columns when the width of the logo exceeds the width of the aside1.

Comment: You can add `#logo {max-width: 300px;}` and `#logo img {width: 100%;} ` to control logo width be no more than 300px;. Using `grid` there is no such a flexible option. Your logo should either less then 300px, or more then 300px widht. Not both. But i don't think the logo will be so wide. In all my projects last 12 year the was no header logo more than 290px wide. You said there is no possibility to rewrite HTML. But can it be rewrited in already browser by JS? If so, I can write for you the most flexible solution on JS

Comment: Thank you. I can't limit the logo to 300px. Some sites include the site title as text which can exceed 300px. I can't use JS in this project, my goal is to be CSS grid only and have a simplified HTML structure with no nesting. I'm trying to create one HTML structure that allows for the creation of all possible website layouts by just making CSS changes. I guess the only realistic solution is to make a different HTML structure which I really wanted to avoid. I will probably end up wrapping aside1, aside2 and article together in a separate grid. This way the columns don't affect each other.

Comment: Yeah. This will be the most right way - to separate header form article with sidebars. I can write down a code for it if you what.